# Loading a DocuSign document on initial boot

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to make it so that when a user turns on their device (will either be a tablet or a laptop) a DocuSign document loads up immediately. The user must sign the agreement before using the device. After that I want them to have access to the device and each boot thereafter I want the device to boot up normally. Can anyone help me with that. I would prefer that the DocuSign document is a pdf, but the format is not the most important variable in this equation. Getting the idea to work is important, I'm completely open as far as file formats and computer languages go. The signed document would be sent to a predetermined email address. Thank you in advance for any help provided. -Domitros

Also, all devices will be running on windows 8
 I was thinking of using a batch file to load the DocuSign document? But, like I said, I'm open to suggestion.

Comment: DocuSign requires a browser to sign. I don't think that you can load a browser before login on any Windows device, but that's where I'd start your search.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done so far is as follows: I created a new standard local account. I set windows to boot up as the newly created user. On their desktop is only 1 icon, a shortcut to the Docusign user agreement that they need to sign. I'm set to receive notification when a document has been signed. Unless I can figure out a means of automation I will have to remote into the users device, via citrix, and erase the user mentioned above and set windows to boot up as the user with access to all the software necessary for the user to do their job. Seems like there is a better  way, but I'm not seeing it.